# How to read .ini file from local system in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to use .env.development, .env.production files in reactjs,

Can you show how to write .env.development file?

Comment: Your question does not give enough information to allow us to help you. I recommend you read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question based on the information there.

Comment: Just as you load any other file, using ajax?